# Wordpress Woocommerce Pass a product name through hard coded URL to the cart and checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata

I have tried to search for a solution for this for the past few days now, and no luck, so thought I'd post on here.

I have a test product page here:

http://scarlettofsoho.wpengine.com/product/test-singlesub-product/

I am looking to pass the product name (Test Single Sub Product) to the checkout/order as metadata when they click on a hardcoded link (which is a different product to (Test Single Sub Product)):

http://scarlettofsoho.wpengine.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=38

Either appended to the URL or put the product name into an input value that submits as metadata to the checkout/order.

Could look something like this?

/?add-to-cart=38&product=test-singlesub-product

Regards, 
Jacques

Comment: Have you tried your idea? What happened? What, specifically, didn't work?

Comment: Been looking at wc_add_order_item_meta() function , if I pass the product name in the query string as /?add-to-cart=38&product=test-singlesub-product and then add that as:

wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique );

with the product $meta_value as the product name?

Not sure if this is a good way to do it?

Comment: Hi Wain, thanks for replying, nothing got passed to the checkout order summary section

Comment: Why do you need to pass the title as item meta? If you have the product ID you can always retrieve the product name.